# Why would "ls -R" on a mounted CDROM fail with e.g. "ls: notes: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, command-line, optical-drive

I popped an old CDROM into my computer and executed

```
ls -lR /Volumes/CDROM
```

and received dozens of error like this:

```
./notes:
ls: notes: No such file or directory
```

but /Volumes/CDROM/notes *does* exist. I can do

```
ls -lR /Volumes/CDROM/notes
```

and get exactly the output I expected.

In fact, I was able to do this:

```
cp -a /Volumes/CDROM/ ~/CDROM
ls -lR ~/CDROM
```

and get the listing I expected.

So far, I've encountered two discs where this happens.

---

More information: Disks were CDRs written in ISO9660 format in 2001 on a Linux or Solaris system. `ls -laiR /Volumes/CDROM` has the same error. I don't believe there are any oddball links. `diskutil list | grep CDROM` indicates CD_ROM_Mode_1.

The error I'm encountering is on disc 2 of 2, which is to say that the other disc written at the same time does not have any errors.

---

Edit #2: including a few lines from `ls -laiR /Volumes/CDROM`

```
Total 1472
  63488 drwxrwxr-x  43 falk  staff    6144 Apr 30  2001 ./
  26680 drwxrwxrwt@  6 root  admin     204 Feb  1 13:40 ../
  69632 drwx------   2 falk  staff    2048 Apr 29  1999 3D/
 487424 drwx------   2 falk  staff    2048 Nov 10  2000 Bonsai/
 489472 drwxrwxr-x   3 falk  staff    2048 Sep 24  1999 Boxes/
 493568 drwx------   2 falk  staff   18432 Apr 30  2001 Calctool/
 512000 drwx------   3 falk  staff    2048 Aug 26  1997 Commander/
 516096 drwx------   2 falk  staff    4096 Apr 30  2001 Connect/
 522240 drwx------  15 falk  staff    4096 Jul 22  2000 Crypt/
 565248 drwx------   7 falk  staff    4096 Jan 27  2000 Doom/
1003520 drwx------   2 falk  staff    2048 Aug  7  1998 DosGames/
1269760 drwxr-xr-x   4 falk  staff    2048 Apr  6  2001 Fft/
2207744 drwx------   7 falk  staff    2048 Jun 24  1998 Java/
2222080 drwx------   2 falk  staff   16384 May 20  1996 Journal/
2238464 drwx------   3 falk  staff    2048 Aug 31  1999 Knapsack/
2250752 drwx--x--x   3 falk  staff    2048 Apr 27  2001 Laptops/
2254848 drwxr-xr-x   5 falk  staff   53248 Apr 30  2001 notes/

/Volumes/CDROM//3D:
total 28
69632 drwx------   2 falk  staff  2048 Apr 29  1999 ./
63488 drwxrwxr-x  43 falk  staff  6144 Apr 30  2001 ../
69836 -rw-rw-r--   1 falk  staff  4494 Apr 29  1999 Notes

/Volumes/CDROM//Doom/wads/editors/deu:
total 48288
614400 drwxrwxr-x  3 falk  staff      4096 Sep  1  1995 ./
589824 drwxrwxr-x  9 falk  staff      2048 Jan 22  1999 ../
614604 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff     59984 Aug 31  1995 CARRIER.BAK
615354 -r--------  2 falk  staff  11159840 Jan 20  1995 DOOM.WAD
614734 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff     59984 Aug 31  1995 carrier.wad
614864 -rwxrwxr-x  1 falk  staff   1138688 Aug 31  1995 deu*
614980 -rwxr-xr-x  1 falk  staff    114688 Jan  2  1995 deutex*
615230 -r--------  2 falk  staff  11159840 Jan 20  1995 doom.wad
615480 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff     95235 Jul 26  1995 gallery.BAK
615610 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff     97903 Sep  1  1995 gallery.wad
615740 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff     74584 Mar  3  1995 gallery0.wad
615872 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff     97015 Jul 26  1995 gallery1.wad
616004 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff      7643 Jul 26  1995 gallery2.BAK
616136 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff      7643 Jul 26  1995 gallery2.wad
616268 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff    119288 Jul 26  1995 mpk14-2.wad
616448 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff     28455 Mar  8  1995 mpk14-2a.wad
616580 -rwxrwxr-x  1 falk  staff     24860 Dec 16  1994 sndserver*
616706 -rwxrwxr-x  1 falk  staff    429956 Dec 16  1994 sunxdoom*
616830 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff      5316 Sep  1  1995 test.BAK
616954 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff      5558 Sep  1  1995 test.wad
618496 drwxrwxr-x  2 falk  staff      4096 Jul 31  1995 tutor/
617194 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff      3265 Jul 26  1995 walkway.BAK
617324 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff      3305 Jul 26  1995 walkway.wad
615100 -rw-rw-r--  1 falk  staff      1162 Sep  1  1995 ~DEU~TMP.WAD

/Volumes/CDROM//Doom/wads/editors/deu/tutor:
ls: tutor: No such file or directory
ls: deu: No such file or directory

/Volumes/CDROM//Doom/wads/editors/deu.X11:
ls: deu.X11: No such file or directory

...

/Volumes/CDROM//Laptops:
ls: Laptops: No such file or directory

/Volumes/CDROM//notes:
ls: notes: No such file or directory
```

Interesting ... once the problem starts happening, it doesn't stop. After one "No such file or directory" error, it's all errors.

And yet, I can cleanly copy this entire CDROM to local disk, and then do a full listing on it.

Comment: More detail _might_ be needed. Are these CDR? If so, what OS burned them. What does `ls -laiR /Volumes/CDROM` show? Any oddball links? Also, what format is the CD? `diskutil list | grep CDROM` might help there...

Comment: I've added more info.

Comment: So nothing at all returns when you try the `-lair` - what's illuminating will be the other files and details in addition to the error message.

Comment: Oh, there's plenty of output with `ls -laiR` -- thousands of lines -- but nothing stuck out. I'll copy/paste a few typical lines into my question.

Comment: Is `notes` a directory? Can you add the result of `ls -ld notes`?

Comment: It's a directory; you can see it listed near the top: `2254848 drwxr-xr-x   5 falk  staff   53248 Apr 30  2001 notes/
`

Comment: OK, my theory is that there must have been two files on the CDROM with the same name except for capitalization, and MacOS fell over when it encountered them. I'll leave the question open in case anybody ever finds an answer, but I'm going to let it rest. Only two CDROMs out of a stack of about thirty showed the problem.